Как получить авторизационный токен для использования API Яндекс.Метрики PHP-скриптом без участия пользователя?
В документации подробно описано, как получить токен "вручную":
https://yandex.ru/dev/metrika/doc/api2/intro/authorization.html

Перейдите по ссылке и на открывшейся странице скопируйте ваш
авторизационный токен.

А есть ли возможность получить токен серверным PHP-скриптом без непосредственного участия пользователя?
